How to Create a Dynamic A < B < C < A Venn Diagram Design in React with HTML/CSS?
I am trying to replicate the Venn diagram design in the attached image

on my React web application using HTML/CSS. The diagram should reflect the relationship A < B < C < A. However, I'm struggling to implement this design correctly.
Requirements:

Layering:

Circle A should be partially covered by Circle B.
Circle B should be partially covered by Circle C.
Circle C should be partially covered by Circle A.


Responsiveness:

The diagram should support responsive design, meaning that the size of each circle should adjust based on hover events or other interactive elements.



Here's my current implementation:
VennDiagram.jsx
import React from 'react';
import styles from './VennDiagram.module.css';

const VennDiagram = ({ a, b, c }) => {
  const points = [
    { x: 0, y: a * 0.75 }, // center of A circle
    { x: b * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI) / 3) * 0.75, y: b * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI) / 3) * 0.75 }, // B circle center
    { x: -c * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI) / 3) * 0.75, y: c * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI) / 3) * 0.75 }, // C circle center
  ];

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <svg className="svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
          <clipPath id="maskA">
            <circle className="circle" cx={points[1].x + 200} cy={points[1].y + 200} r={b * 0.75} />
          </clipPath>
          <clipPath id="maskB">
            <circle className="circle" cx={points[2].x + 200} cy={points[2].y + 200} r={c * 0.75} />
          </clipPath>
          <clipPath id="maskC">
            <circle className="circle" cx={points[0].x + 200} cy={points[0].y + 200} r={a * 0.75} />
          </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <circle
          cx={points[0].x + 200}
          cy={points[0].y + 200}
          r={a * 0.75}
          fill="rgba(0, 123, 255, 1)"
          clipPath="url(#maskC)"
        />
        <circle
          cx={points[1].x + 200}
          cy={points[1].y + 200}
          r={b * 0.75}
          fill="rgba(255, 123, 0, 1)"
          clipPath="url(#maskA)"
        />
        <circle
          cx={points[2].x + 200}
          cy={points[2].y + 200}
          r={c * 0.75}
          fill="rgba(0, 255, 123, 1)"
          clipPath="url(#maskB)"
        />
        <circle cx={points[0].x + 200} cy={points[0].y + 200} r={a * 0.75} fill="rgba(0, 123, 255, 1)" />
      </svg>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VennDiagram;

VennDiagram.module.css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
}

Problem
I can't figure out how to implement the correct overlaps to match the Venn diagram design, where A < B < C < A. The circles are drawn, but I am not sure how to arrange them to reflect the specific relational design.
Additionally, I need to make this diagram responsive, allowing for circle sizes to adjust based on hover events or other interactions.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I tried the mask from css but I failed to make it.
And I tried the Image option but this is not what i want(for responsiveness)
and the last try was Svg, but I failed(I'm not very familiar with dealing with svg so I have no idea how.)

use paths and arcs. You can always use an SVG editor such as Inkscape to create whatever SVG you need.

@RobertLongson So, can I create a responsive design using SVG?

Sure, there are many questions and answers here already on that.

Here is the plain SVG. I use one circle element and use that for construction the different elements including the mask.
How you would like the interactivity is not clear. Making the circles larger will mess up the relationship/position with the other circles.


body {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="98vh">
  <defs>
    <circle id="c1" r="30" />
    <mask id="m1">
      <use href="#c1" fill="white" />
      <use href="#c1" fill="black" transform="rotate(30) translate(-30 0)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-30)">
    <use href="#c1" fill="#ccc" />
    <use class="blue" transform="rotate(0) translate(17.2 0)" href="#c1"
      fill="SkyBlue" mask="url(#m1)" />
    <use transform="rotate(120) translate(17.2 0)" href="#c1"
      fill="PaleGreen" mask="url(#m1)" />
    <use transform="rotate(240) translate(17.2 0)" href="#c1"
      fill="Tomato" mask="url(#m1)" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(-30)" font-family="sans-serif"
    font-size="5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
    <text fill="white" transform="rotate(0) translate(32 0) rotate(30)">Blue</text>
    <text fill="black" transform="rotate(120) translate(32 0) rotate(-90)">Green</text>
    <text fill="black" transform="rotate(240) translate(32 0) rotate(-210)">Red</text>
    <text fill="black" transform="rotate(30)">Gray</text>
  </g>
</svg>




Respect... I spent almost two hours on this, and I was not able to procedurally figure out this gray middle of the diagram.
